# How can you select all even numbered position items from IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

How can you select all even numbered position from `IEnumerable`?

Say I have `IEnumerable<int>` as

```
3,5,7,9,10
```

Output should be `5, 9`.

Which lambda do I need to write?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the overload of [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx) with the predicate function that also takes the index:

```
IEnumerable<int> result = ints.Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var nums = new int[] { 3, 5, 7, 9, 10 };

var results = nums.Where((n, i) => i % 2 != 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need:

```
int[] values = new[] {3,5,7,9,10};
var everyOtherValue = values.Where((v, idx) => idx % 2 != 0);
```